# Pushing to an array on div click

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to show an array when someone clicks a div that is made up of the ids of those divs. What I have so far keeps replacing the values rather than adding to it. I get one two or three rather than one,two,three which is what I want. I think it might be how I am using the click function but I am not sure.

```
<div class="status" id="one">1</div>
<div class="status" id="three">333</div>
<div class="status" id="two">22</div>

<p id="demo">The array.</p>

$('.status').click(function() {
    var status = $(this).attr('id');
    var list = []; 
    list.push(status)
    //alert(status); 

    var x=document.getElementById("demo");
    x.innerHTML=list;
});
```

Have a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3zDZC/

Comment: init list outside of click handler;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you keep re-creating the array.  You want to create the array outside the handler.

Also, instead of setting innerHTML to the array, you'll want to call join on the array so the div's contents take the values of what's *in the* array.

```
var list = []; 
$('.status').click(function() {
    var status = $(this).attr('id');

    list.push(status)
    //alert(status); 

    var x=document.getElementById("demo");
    x.innerHTML=list.join(', ');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You keep clearing the array on every click. Move `var list = [];` to be outside the click handler:

```
var list = [];
$('.status').click(function () {
    var status = $(this).attr('id');
    list.push(status)
    //alert(status); 
    var x = document.getElementById("demo");
    x.innerHTML = list;
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/3zDZC/1/)**

And since you're using jQuery, you can change this:

```
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
x.innerHTML = list;
```

to just:

```
$('#demo').html(list);
```